# How to define spectral multiplier for −Δ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sp.spectral-theory

Put $e_{n}(t)=e^{int}=\prod_{j=1}^{d}e^{in_{j}t_{j}}$, $t\in \mathbb T^d, n\in \mathbb Z^d.$  ($t=(t_{1},..., t_d), n=(n_1,..., n_d)$)
We note that $\{e_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z^d}$ forms an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}(\mathbb T^d).$ And so for $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb T^d),$ we may write $f= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z^{d}} <f, e_n> e_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P_{k}f,$ where $ P_{k}f= \sum_{k=|n|}<f, e_n> e_{n}, |n|= n_{1}+...+n_d$ (convergence in $L^2-$ sense).

We consider $T=-\Delta = -\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ on $\mathbb T^d,$ and note that $T(e_{n})=n^{2} e_{n}$. Thus $\{e_n\}$ forms an eigen functions for $T$ with eigen value $n^2.$

My Question is:

> (1)Can we say spectral decomposition of $T$ takes the form as follows:
>   $$T= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 P_k,$$ where $P_k$ is defined as above. (I may be wrong, please correct me if I have made any mistake.) If yes, how to justify using spectral theorem.

(My just learning to use spectral [Theorem 1.5 (page no. 7)](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/multipliers.pdf) in this note. What should be the regular resolution of identity in this theorem for $-\Delta$? Why integral becomes sum? )

> (2) How should I define spectral multiplier for $-\Delta$? (See [page 8](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/multipliers.pdf) in this note for definition.) Can you motivate this definition bit more?

[Side thoughts: What will be the analogue this on $\mathbb R^d.$ Why authors consider $-\Delta$ instead of $\Delta$]